# How to add an Azure File share as a volume in Azure Pipeline

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-storage, gitlab-ci.yml

I'm using Azure Devops to build and push a docker container to the container registry.

I need to enable persistent storage. So I've created a file system and a fileshare. How would I now go about adding this file share to the resulting web app container when it's deployed? Say at a path of /var/www/html/shared_storage

My yml file for the pipeline is:

```
trigger:
- master

resources:
- repo: self

variables:
  dockerRegistryServiceConnection: 'xxxx'
  imageRepository: 'xxx'
  containerRegistry: 'xxx.azurecr.io'
  dockerfilePath: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/Dockerfile'
  vmImageName: 'ubuntu-latest'
  
  - stage: Build_Master
    condition: eq(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/master')
    displayName: Build master
    jobs:
    - job: Build
      displayName: Build
      pool:
        vmImage: $(vmImageName)
      steps:
      - task: Docker@2
        displayName: Build and push an image to container registry
        inputs:
          command: buildAndPush
          repository: $(imageRepository)
          dockerfile: $(dockerfilePath)
          containerRegistry: $(dockerRegistryServiceConnection)
          tags: |
            master
```

I was hoping I could specify the connection details and then provide something like:
volumes
shared_storage:/var/www/html/shared_storage

But I can't seem to find any documentation for this.

Comment: Try to look into this thread, it is about blob and not file share but I think it might be helpful too as approach pretty the same: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60741286/mounting-azure-blob-storage-in-docker-file

Comment: just to clarify azure container apps or azure web app for containers? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/webapp/config/storage-account?view=azure-cli-latest , you can mount it like this  '''az webapp config storage-account add -g MyResourceGroup -n MyUniqueApp \
  --custom-id CustomId \
  --storage-type AzureFiles \
  --account-name MyStorageAccount \
  --share-name MyShare \
  --access-key MyAccessKey \
  --mount-path /path/to/mount''' example here https://www.codit.eu/blog/mounting-volumes-on-azure-web-app-for-containers/

Comment: Thanks Sysanin and Anass, I've just found an option in the azure portal that allows me to add a fileshare. Anass, your comment was a good indication this was possible, it's a little hiddden in the UI. Thank you both! If you would like to post your comment as an answer @AnassKartit I will edit to include the UI view that accomadates this functionality and mark as accepted

Comment: I added the answer feel free to contribute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can mount a storage account to an Azure Web App for Containers using the following Azure CLI command:

```bash
az webapp config storage-account add --resource-group MyResourceGroup --name MyUniqueApp \
  --custom-id CustomId --storage-type AzureFiles \
  --account-name MyStorageAccount --share-name MyShare \
  --access-key MyAccessKey --mount-path /path/to/mount
```

Additionally, if using a Web App, in the Azure portal you can  go to Configuration->path mappings and add a 'Storage Mount' to a filesystem in there.